How to set margins in QHorizontalStackedBarSeries PyQt6?
How can I adjust the margins in a QHorozintalStackedBar Graph? I have made a placeholder widget in qt designer, added the custom bar chart and can populate it. But for the life of me I can´t change the way the widget occupies it´s own space. There is too much empty space. Non of my margin settings in my code seem to affect it:
`series = QHorizontalStackedBarSeries()
    bar_set1 = QBarSet("Max UE")
    bar_set1.append(max_ue)
    print("Bar set 1 Val:", max_ue)

    bar_set2 = QBarSet("Min UE")
    bar_set2.append(min_ue)
    print("Bar set 2 Val:", min_ue)

    bar_set3 = QBarSet("UE aktuell")
    bar_set3.append(ue_aktuell)
    print("Bar set 3 Val:", ue_aktuell)
    
    
    bar_set1.setColor(QColor(103, 181, 108))   
    bar_set2.setColor(QColor(128, 128, 128))  
    bar_set3.setColor(QColor(94, 125, 171))   
    
    series.append(bar_set3)
    series.append(bar_set2)
    series.append(bar_set1)
    series.setLabelsVisible(True)
    
    series.setBarWidth(0.5)  
    
    chart = QChart()
    chart.addSeries(series)
    chart.setTitle("Kurs Ziel-O-Meter")
    chart.setTitleBrush(QColor(Qt.GlobalColor.white))
    
    legend = chart.legend()
    chart.legend().setBrush(QColor(Qt.GlobalColor.white))
    chart.legend().setLabelColor(QColor(Qt.GlobalColor.white))
    layout = legend.layout()
    if layout:
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(2, 0, 2, 0)
    legend.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignBottom)
    
    
    chart.setMargins(QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0))
    
    chart_view = QChartView(chart)
    chart_view.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())  
    
    chart_view.chart().setMargins(QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0));
    
    chart_view.layout().setContentsMargins(1, 0, 1, 0)  #
    chart_view.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
    layout = self.ui.barWidget.layout()
    if layout is None:
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.ui.barWidget.setLayout(layout)
    layout.addWidget(chart_view)
    
    self.layout().setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
    parent_widget = self.ui.barWidget
    parent_width = parent_widget.width()
    parent_height = parent_widget.height()

    print("Parent width:", parent_width)
    print("Parent height:", parent_height)
    chart_view.setGeometry(0, 0, parent_widget.width(), parent_widget.height())
    chart_view.chart().setBackgroundVisible = True
    chart_view.chart().setBackgroundBrush(QColor("#242424"))
    
    self.ui.barWidget.layout().addWidget(chart_view)`

